# Use ffmpeg as external tool to stream 2 or more different sources via pipeline

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, real-time, rtp

I have an application running on an embedded system. This application has 2 video sources (and, theorically, 1 audio source). Concentrating to the video sources, I have 2 subprocess that computes different frames sets (unrelated each others). I want to send these frames to 2 differents streams.

I would to avoid to write a lot of ffmpeg/libav code. I have ffmpeg compiled for the embeeded system and I can use it as tool. For example, I can write to the stdout the first frames set and pass it to the ffmpeg like this:

`./my_app|ffmpeg -an -i - -vcodec copy -f rtp rtp://"remote_ip`

This basically works. But, now i would to send the other one frame set. How to do that? Theorically I need anoter ffmpeg instance that read from another source that can't be the stdout of "my_app", because is already busy.

---

I'm thinking to use 2 video files as support. I can record the 2 frames sets into 2 video files and then run 2 ffmpeg instances from these sources. In this case I think I need a way to limit the video files dimensions (like a circular buffer), because 2 streams can become really huge in time. It is a possibility?
This can sound "weird" to me: I need to record a video source in realtime and stream it via ffmpeg (always in realtime). I don't know if it is a good idea, there are realtime problems for sure:

```
loop:
my_app --write_into--> video_stream1.mp4 
ffmpeg <--read_from-- video_stream1.mp4

my_app --write_into--> video_stream2.mp4 
ffmpeg <--read_from-- video_stream2.mp4
```

Have you some suggestion to address this kind of situation?

many thanks, bye.

Comment: Why not have each `ffmpeg` instance as a child process of `my_app`?  Just feed the data to the correct instance as/when it arrives.  If that *is* an option you might want to have a look at [`boost.process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/process.html).

Comment: I can exec ffmpeg from my_app. This is a linux (arm) process so I can call something like /bin/sh ffmpeg ... from my_app. The problem is: do ffmpeg take frame-by-frame as input? Having a "static" video I can call ffmpeg as child, this works. I don't know having a real-time acquisition frame-by-frame...

Comment: I'm thinking that a good way can be socat. I can write frames on a tcp socket, then read them via socat and do many pipeline as I want with ffmpeg. I'm trying this way now and partially works....Partially because I'm not able right now to maintain a stable session...